# How I can know directive has been completely compiled in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, directive, compiled

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
  <title>test directive</title>
</head>
<body ng-controller="bodyController">

  <hello alert="outAlert"></hello>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.bootcss.com/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  angular.module("myApp", [])

  .directive("hello", function(){
    return {
      scope: {
        alert: "="
      },
      link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
        scope.alert = function(msg){
          window.alert(msg)
        }
      }
    }
  })

  .controller("bodyController", function($scope, $timeout){
    $scope.outAlert("this occurs an error: undefined is not a function")

    $timeout(function(){
      $scope.outAlert("this works great!")
    }, 100)
  })
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

As above code, `hello` directive transfers `outAlert` function to `bodyController`. But `bodyController` can not use `outAlert` immediately or it will occur an error "undefined is not a function".

So I have to run it after 100ms. But it doesn't look like a formal solution. I want to seek for a better way!

How I can know directive has been completely compiled in angularjs???

Comment: You are redefining the alert passed into the directive inside your `link`. Doesn't make sense. Create a demo that includes the basic html and replicates your problem. Also doesn't make sense that your controller can't use a function that is defined within it except that you are overwriting it if it is also beeing passed into the link

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this? I think what you should be using is custom scope events with `$on` and `$emit` instead if trying to two-way bind with function objects.

Answer (score 0):

After my practise these months, it'd better to provide a callback in the directive to the outside component because the directives must be completely compiled if it invokes the callback providing by itself.

(My English is poor! Can you understant?)